# I have ID, purchasedate, purchaseprice columns. I have to get IDs whose total of purchase price in June is less than 50% of total purchase in May

Tags: r, dplyr

```
        ID     ordernum  orderdate           orderprice operiod
     <dbl>         <dbl> <dttm>                   <dbl> <chr>  
 1  550592 1003131392645 2019-03-21 00:00:00     375280 14.9   
 2  598210 1003131414321 2019-03-21 00:00:00     125900 7.08   
 3 1388173 1003131368822 2019-03-21 00:00:00      87440 15.89  
 4  545052 1003131516374 2019-03-21 00:00:00      57600 84.55  
 5  305776 1003131547399 2019-03-21 00:00:00      54500 0.95   
 6 1958921 1003131536979 2019-03-21 00:00:00      90150 8.56   
 7 1484607 1003131320092 2019-03-21 00:00:00      58700 87.9
```

...

THis is so far what I have treid

```
ordd1<-ORD %>% 
  mutate(orderm=month(orderdate))

  ordd2<-group_by(ordd1,ID,orderm) %>%
    filter(ordd2,orderm == "2019-05" & orderm == "2019-06")
```

I would like to get the result like

```
ID

1201230

123091231
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

R's vectorization ability is efficient and powerful.

```
df <- data[data$date == "May"]
df$ID[df$date == "June" & df$total_purchase_price < 0.5]
```